# Entity Framework - Maintain property when adding/removing entity

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, model

In entity framework I set the property "StoreGeneratedPattern" to be "computed" on one of my entity columns.

The problem I face is if someone removes that entity and re-adds it for whatever reason that property setting is lost.

What is the best way to override this and ensure that the property setting is maintained at all times?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you use model first or code first?

Comment: Model. DB is designed and model is then built based on that structure.